# How to define date column and plot that date column as x axis in R studio

Tags: date, plot, time-series

I have half-hourly time series data; 48 data points in a day. The total time period starts from 4/6/2018 (i.e day/month/year) to 2/12/2018. I want to create a time series object. I am using ts function.

However, I am unable to define the frequency. As I know, frequency=1 for yearly data, but unable to define in my half-hourly data. How to solve this problem using ts object or there is any other way to do it?

After creating a time series object (i.e. date column), I want to plot it with the corresponding data series.

How to plot my result (in R object) on Y-axis and time period on the X-axis?

```
R <- function(x){
return(FDWhittle(x, method="discrete", sdf.method="multitaper"))
}
plot(R[,i],type="l",col = "Black", xlab="Time",
   ylab="Return",main=names(R)[,i])
```

When I am plotting by using the above code, the results in the object "R" is coming on the Y-axis, and some values like (100, 200, 300--------) are coming on the X-axis. I want to get the time period on my X axis, but unable to define the intra-day date column having 48 data points in a day.